# Open Management Studio with configured connections

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Maybe this question is a little off topic, I will close if necessary, but, is there a way to configure Management studio, to when I open it, it starts already with x connections? So I don't need to start it and connect to x instances every time.

Comment: Closest I have seen is creating a group in registered servers and opening a connection to all those servers by one click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure of a way to do this 'natively' in SSMS, but I've been using [SSMS Boost](http://www.ssmsboost.com/) for years and it has that functionality (and a whole lot more). It's a plugin for SSMS and they have a 'free' community version that just needs to be re-downloaded every few months.

Check [here](http://www.ssmsboost.com/social/posts/m12228-SSMSBoost-v3-0-Beta--2008-2012-2014) and scroll down until you see ***Download links (updated on 14-th of March 2017):***

After installation, there will be a new menu bar option 'SSMSBoost'. Click on the menu bar and select 'Settings'.  Then look for 'Preferred Connections'.  There, you will have a checkbox to open a defined connection on SSMS startup.

[image]

You can 'add' preferred connections by clicking the 'plus' sign at the bottom of the screen.  Preferred connections also allow you to specify an 'Important DB Alert' that will actually be displayed on new query windows - I use mine to inform me I'm in a 'production' database.

Comment: Oh Nice, Will try it and post results. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use free "SSMSConnect" extension for SSMS, which I developed to solve this issue.

https://github.com/ikarasin/SSMSConnect

SSMS versions 18 and 19 are currently supported.

Comment: Hi Ilia, this is the second identical answer and it is starting to look like spamming.  Please read the help on self promotion and  explain a bit about your program.

Comment: Hi Rohit, when I firstly faced this issue, Google led me to a couple of threads here, and no solution in them (I checked SSMSBoost and it doesn't seem to support latest version of SSMS, and seems to be abandoned in 2021). So I developed my own tool, and just returned to these threads to share it, so people with the same request could use it. Didn't mean to spam of course. Thanks!